# I need to list the path to all files in directory and sub directories and the creation date of the file in windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window, file-listing

I saw similar questions but nothing is working yet.

The end goal is to get a csv with col1 being file path and col2 being creation date.

Lets assume i have a directory C:/dir1, and inside it I have C:/dir1a and C:/dir1b and dir1a and dir1b both have files in them.

I can do

```
dir /s /b > dirfiles.csv
```

Which does give me all the file names, however when I do

```
dir /S /B /T:C > dirfiles_time.csv
```

nothing different happens.

How can i create a list of paths to every file (not directory just the files) and the creation time of that file?

Thanks

EDIT
I do not care about the actual directory, only the path to the files themselves.  Remove /b leaves a lot of information that i would need to remove

```
 Directory of D:\Dir1\dir1a

03/29/2018  11:20 AM    <DIR>          .
03/29/2018  11:20 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/29/2018  11:20 AM         5,583,992 16385  yadayada.tif
03/29/2018  11:20 AM         9,560,580 2278 yada.jpg
           2 File(s)     15,144,572 bytes
```

Comment: What do you think the `/b` does?

Comment: when i did /s without /b there was a lot of unnecessary info mixed into the file, and /b stripped away the info that i did not need.  Is this wrong?

Comment: It is if some of that info was the time you wanted!

Comment: So is there a way to ignore all directories and JUST print paths to files and their time?

Comment: othwerise every new directory has these extra lines which will make a lot of manual work (thousands of directories)
 Directory of D:\dir1\dir1a

03/29/2018  11:20 AM    <DIR>          .
03/29/2018  11:20 AM    <DIR>          ..
usefull data here
 11 File(s)     14,600,130 bytes

Comment: That's why you use a `for /f` loop to tokenize the string and only print the parts of the line that you need.

Comment: If you just need the modified time, you can use a `FOR /R` command to get the information you want by using the command modifiers. If you want the created time, then you need to parse the output of the `DIR` command with the `FOR /F` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit in with your `[batch-file]` tag, just run this `PowerShell` command from the batch file.

```bat
@Powershell -NoP -C "GCI $(GCI \"D:\Dir1\"|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{$_.FullName}) -R|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Select FullName,CreationTime|Export-CSV -NoT \"dirfiles_time.csv\""
```

You can change the initial directory, `D:\Dir1`, and csv output file, `dirfiles_time.csv`, just take care not to delete their opening and closing, `\"` sequence.

*If you want only the filenames without their paths then change `Select FullName,CreationTime` to `Select Name,CreationTime`. Likwise If you'd prefer the last modified times, change `Select FullName,CreationTime` to `Select FullName,LastWriteTime`.*

Comment: hhmm did this run for you?  it is saying missing the terminator " at char 222, I will take a deeper look at it tomorrow

Comment: I have now tested it and it works perfectly on two different units functioning exactly as intended. _I even opened the csv in Excel to check it without issue._ You have obviously made a mistake when changing the directory and/or csv file, _you have added at least 50 characters to what I posted!_ The instructions for changing those things were clear, if the directory was **C:\Users\Eddie**, **`\"C:\Users\Eddie\"`** and if the csv was **C:\Users\Eddie\Desktop\mycsv.csv**, **`\"C:\Users\Eddie\Desktop\mycsv.csv\"`** followed by the closing doublequote, **`"`**.

Comment: You are right, im an idiot.  Thats why I shouldn't do this stuff late at night.  This worked perfectly when I followed what you said about the trailing \